# How can you use PowerShell to get a tree list of directories and metadata

Tags: powershell, directory, tree, metadata, hierarchy

I'd like to generate a tree list of folders and sub-folders as well as the names and owners of the files within them. E.g.:

```
FOLDER

>File0.ppt - Owner0

>SUBFOLDER_1

    >File1.1.docx - Owner_A

    >File1.2.pdf - Owner_B

>SUBFOLDER_2

    >File2.1.xlsx - Owner A
```

Any ideas how I can get this? I know how to get one or the other, but not both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is alternate ways to do it but I tried to respect the output as text.
As object this would be a one-liner.

```
Function Recurse($folder, $lvl) {

    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name) - $((Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner)"
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name)"
        Recurse -folder $_.FullName -lvl $($lvl+1)
    }
}

$root = Get-Item -Path $path
Recurse -folder $root.FullName -lvl 0
```

Comment: Thanks, Hazrelle.
What would I need to edit so that I begin from a specific folder?
And how would you define $lvl?

Comment: `$path = "C:\MyFolder"` that's all :) $lvl is just to maintain a counter. Should always be 0 when you call the function. It is just there to provide "spaces" when writing the folder name or file name, so that you can visualize the hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if it had to be $Folder or $Path.
How would I output this as a .csv file?

Comment: CSV is a flat file, and is not intended to display a hierarchy. Json is more suitable for this kind of representation. But if you want a flatten display, then the script is even easier.
$path = "c:\analyse"
$outpath = "c:\myfolder\mycsvout.csv"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path | Select-Object Name, @{l="Type";e={ if ($_.Attributes.HasFlag([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory)) { "Directory" } else {"File" }}}, 
  @{l="Owner"; e={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}} | Export-Csv -Path $outpath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ';'

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, this new code doesn't output the information in a hierarchical order. Is there any other way to export the output so that it looks like in my original question?

Comment: You have to choose between simple text that may display the hierarchy (see my answer). Or a CSV file format which represent a list of data organized in columns (no hierarchy). Json or XML are more suitable to represent a hierarchy.